# Getting a "Page X of Y" message in Wordpress' single.php

Tags: php, wordpress, themes, wordpress-theming

I'm wondering how i can make i.e *'Page 2 of 13'* appear on the bottom of Wordpress' *single.php* page.

Let's say a user clicks a post title on the front page, and when it's opened with *single.php* the user sees what page he's on (and also how many are total). So if he chooses to view the third post it would say *'Post 3 of 13'*. If he then clicks Next or Previous, he gets *'Post 2 of 13'*, or *'Post 4 of 13'* and so on.

I've managed to do this on the front page, but can't seem to get it working properly on *single.php*

The reason i want this is to have the message between a prev and next arrow.

Comment: Would this not be better asked at wordpress.stackexchange.com ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

posts_nav_link();

previous_post();

next_post();

Refer [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Next_and_Previous_Links)

Answer (score 0):

Here's an easy way that will work in your sidebar:

```
<?php
$page_id = $post->ID;
$page_parent = $post->post_parent;
if ($page_parent) { // there's a parent page, get the children
$args = array(
'parent' => $page_parent,
'child_of' => $page_parent,
'hierarchical' => 0,
'sort_column' => 'menu_order'
);
}
else { // no parent, so just get top level pages
$args = array(
'parent' => 0,
'sort_column' => 'menu_order'
);
}
$my_pages = get_pages($args);
while ($page = current($my_pages)) { // find this page's position in the page array
if ($page->ID == $page_id) {
echo key($my_pages) + 1;
}
next($my_pages);
}
$result = count($my_pages);
echo " of " . $result;
?>
```